# Spring Actuator check - adding if-none-matches to header params

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, actuator

I am working on Spring Boot upgrade to 3.2. In this upgrade when the spring health check happens it triggers the health check URL as https://localhost:8443/actuator. The check fails with the error
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot invoke "java.util.Enumeration.hasMoreElements()" because "ifNoneMatchHeaders" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Enumeration.hasMoreElements()" because "ifNoneMatchHeaders" is null    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.validateIfNoneMatch(ServletWebRequest.java:247)    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified(ServletWebRequest.java:225)   at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified(ServletWebRequest.java:199)

Then we found that we have to sent if-non-matches along with the header. But how to add header param only for health check?